# Reading text using a function like sprintf in R

Tags: r, string, text, printf

Suppose I have the following text:

```
"    7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013"
```

I know it's format:

```
" %9.4f  %9.4f  %9.4f  %9.4f"
```

I want to extract variables out of it. I want something like `sprintf`/`gettextf` function but does does the reverse:

```
??????(" %9.4f  %9.4f  %9.4f  %9.4f", v1, v2, v3, v4)
```

How can I do that? (without loading any packages, if possible)

The unreliable method I use right now is:

```
temp <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit("    7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013"," ")))
temp[!is.na(temp)]
```

Comment: How about `read.table(text = " 7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013")`? Can you think of situations where it may fail?

Comment: @konvas Much better than what I currently do. It will work for my current situation. But I am looking for a general solution, like one that can read three letters in this: `read.table(text = sprintf("%1s-%1s-%1s","a","c","e"))` separately.

Comment: Or `read.fwf` for reading "fixed-width" files (if values ever run together). R will store them all as a generic "numeric" type anyway.

Comment: For that example, `read.table(text = sprintf("%1s-%1s-%1s","a","c","e"), sep="-")` would do

Comment: You can also always use a regular expression if you know exactly what pattern you are looking for (ie using `gregexpr` and `regmatches`).

Comment: @MrFlick I cannot make `read.fwf(text = " 7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013",widths = c(10,9,9,9))` work.

Comment: @HBat Well, `read.fwf` doesn't support `text=`, but `read.fwf(textConnection(" 7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013"),widths = c(10,10,10,10))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
scan(text="  7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013")
#Read 4 items
#[1] 7.7597 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013
```

It correctly reports `NA`s:

```
scan(text="   7.7597  NA   4.7389     3.0058     0.0013")
#Read 5 items
#[1] 7.7597     NA 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013
```

It breaks on malformed input (non-numeric). So you can control it with a `tryCatch`:

```
tryCatch(scan(text=" abc  7.7597  4.7389"), error= function(e) cat("Malformed input\n")) 
#Malformed input
```

**Under the hood**

How come that `scan` gets the floats properly? The function has an argument, `what`, to set the data type you are scanning for. The default parameter is

```
scan(...,  what=double())
```

So it parses pretty well the floats required in the question. Anyway, should you change your needs and looking for different data types, try:

```
scan(text="  7  4  3  0 ", what=integer())
#Read 4 items
#[1] 7 4 3 0
```

As usual you can check for data consistency:

```
tryCatch(scan(text=" 1 2.3", what=integer()), error= function(e) cat("Non-integer value(s) passed!\n")) 
#Non-integer value(s) passed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your method more reliable, instead of searching for something that may not even exist.

```
> x <- "    7.7597     4.7389     3.0058     0.0013"

> unlist(read.table(text = x, strip.white = TRUE), use.names = FALSE)
# [1] 7.7597 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013

> as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\s+"), "[", -1))
# [1] 7.7597 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013

> as.numeric(strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]])[-1]
# [1] 7.7597 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013

> library(stringr)
> as.numeric(strsplit(str_trim(x), "\\s+")[[1]])
# [1] 7.7597 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013

> as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, "[0-9][.][0-9]+")[[1]])
# [1] 7.7597 4.7389 3.0058 0.0013
```